# Deterministic execution time on x86-64

Tags: performance, timer, x86, cpu-architecture

Is there an x64 instruction(s) that takes a fixed amount of time, regardless of the micro-architectural state such as caches, branch predictors, etc.?

For instance, if a hypothetical add or increment instruction always takes n cycles, then I can implement a timer in my program by performing that add instruction multiple times. Perhaps an increment instruction with register operands may work, but it's not clear to me whether Intel's spec guarantees that it would take deterministic number of cycles. Note that I am not interested in current time, but only a primitive / instruction sequence that takes a fixed number of cycles.

Assume that I have a way to force atomic execution i.e. no context switches during timer's execution i.e. only my program gets to run.
On a related note, I also cannot use system services to keep track of time, because I am working in a setting where my program is a user-level program running on an untrusted OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x86 ISA documents don't guarantee anything about what takes a certain amount of cycles.  The ISA allows things like [Transmeta's Crusoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmeta_Crusoe) that JIT-compiled x86 instructions to an internal VLIW instruction set.  It could conceivably do optimizations between adjacent instructions.

The best you can do is **write something that will work on as many known microarchitectures as possible**.  I'm not aware of any x86-64 microarchitectures that are "weird" like Transmeta, only the usual superscalar decode-to-uops designs like Intel and AMD use.

**Simple integer ALU instructions like ADD are almost all 1c latency, and tiny loops that don't touch memory are almost totally unaffected anything, and are very predictable**.  If they run a lot of iterations, they're also almost totally unaffected by anything to do with the impact of surrounding code on the out-of-order core, and recover very quickly from disruptions like timer interrupts.

---

On nearly every Intel microarchitecture, this loop will run at one iteration per clock:

```
mov   ecx, 1234567   ; or use a 64-bit register for higher counts.

ALIGN 16
.loop:
 sub  ecx, 1      ; not dec because of Pentium 4.
 jnz  .loop
```

[Agner Fog's microarch guide and instruction tables](http://agner.org/optimize/) say that VIA Nano3000 has a taken-branch throughput of one per 3 cycles, so this loop would only run at one iteration per 3 clocks there.  AMD Bulldozer-family and Jaguar similarly have a max throughput of one taken JCC per 2 clocks.

See also other performance links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

If you want a more power-efficient loop, you could use [PAUSE](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PAUSE.html) in the loop, but it waits ~100 cycles on Skylake, up from ~5 cycles on previous microarchitectures.  (You can make cycle-accurate predictions for more complicated loops that don't touch memory, but that depends on microarchitectural details.)

---

You could make a more reliable loop that's less likely to have different bottlenecks on different CPUs by making a longer dependency chain within each iteration.  Since each instruction depends on the previous, it can still only run at one instruction per cycle (not counting the branch), drastically the branches per cycle.

```
# one add/sub per clock, limited by latency
# should run one iteration per 6 cycles on every CPU listed in Agner Fog's tables
# And should be the same on all future CPUs unless they do magic inter-instruction optimizations.
# Or it could be slower on CPUs that always have a bubble on taken branches, but it seems unlikely anyone would design one.
ALIGN 16
.loop:
 add  ecx, 1
 sub  ecx, 1   ; net result ecx+0
 add  ecx, 1
 sub  ecx, 1   ; net result ecx+0
 add  ecx, 1
 sub  ecx, 2   ; net result ecx-1
 jnz  .loop
```

Unrolling like this ensures that front-end effects are not a bottleneck.  It gives the frontend decoders plenty of time to queue up the 6 add/sub insns and the jcc before the next branch.

Using add/sub instead of dec/inc avoids a partial-flag false dependency on Pentium 4.  (Although I don't think that would be an issue anyway.)

Pentium4's double-clocked ALUs can each run two ADDs per clock, but the latency is still one cycle.  i.e. apparently it can't forward a result internally to chew through this dependency chain twice as fast as any other CPU.

And yes, Prescott P4 is an x86-64 CPU, so we can't quite ignore P4 if we need a general purpose answer.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer! That answered all of my questions. I should mention that a solution that works for Skylake and future would suffice.